# rbind list of data frames with one column of characters and numerics

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have a list of two data frames with the same column names, but different number of rows, rbind.fill can help to put them together into a big data frame, but the problem is that the first column in df1 is numeric data, and df2 is character data, when they are merged, the character data all become 1, I've searched around, but didn't get the problem fixed, any help would be appreciated. A small example would be:

```
station <- c(1:10)
value <- c(101:110)  
df1 <- data.frame(cbind(station,value)) 
station <- c("a","b")
value <- c(101:102)  
df2 <- data.frame(cbind(station,value)) 
data1 <- rbind.fill(df1,df2)
```

I would like the characters remain as characters, thanks.

Comment: But usually each column in a data frame has the same class ?

Comment: rbind.fill isn't in base R.  I believe that is a plyr function - is that where you are getting it from?  Also all columns in a data frame need to be the same time so what is your expected output?

Comment: @liuminzhao,@Dason,Thanks for the reply, so maybe change the numeric data to character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not character if it's turning it to numeric, it's a factor.  Use `str` to check this.  This will get you going:

```
df2$station <- as.character(df2$station)
```

EDIT: or use keep R from converting strings to factors when you crate the data frame:

```
df2 <- data.frame(cbind(station,value), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Console output:

```
> station <- c(1:10)
> value <- c(101:110)  
> df1 <- data.frame(cbind(station,value)) 
> station <- c("a","b")
> value <- c(101:102)  
> df2 <- data.frame(cbind(station,value)) 
> df2$station <- as.character(df2$station)
> 
> library(plyr)
> data1 <- rbind.fill(df1,df2)
> data1
   station value
1        1   101
2        2   102
3        3   103
4        4   104
5        5   105
6        6   106
7        7   107
8        8   108
9        9   109
10      10   110
11       a     1
12       b     2
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like going in the right direction, but one problem here is that this is just an small example, in my real data, about more than 500 data frames are in character/factor and the other 500 are in numeric, how can I do with my data??

Comment: I think the strings as factor in the dataframe is what you're after.

Comment: exactly, I changed the code and it works perfectly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you don't have to use `rbind.fill` because your data frames do have the same column names. Just try `rbind` which will work just fine.
You statet that you are using a list, so you might want to know this little trick with `do.call`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(station = 1:10, value = 101:110) 
df2 <- data.frame(station = c("a","b"), value = 101:102) 
(data1 <- rbind.fill(df1,df2))
rbind(df1,df2)

dfl <- list(df1,df2)
do.call("rbind",dfl)
```

Note that I have kind of "cleaned" your example code. You don't have to concatenate everything.